# How to Solve this error, while making apache Virual Host?

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, apache-virtualhost

I have Install the LAMP on my new server and want to make an Apache Virtual Host. First of all, I install the Updates on CentOS 7 by command `sudo yum updates`. Second, after update the Server, I install the LAMP stack and continue to make Apache Virtual Host. After making Apache Virtual Host, when I go to restart the Apache by command `sudo apachectl restart`, I get an error.

Error Result

```
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

When I try to enter the following command I get an error.

Command: **systemctl status httpd.service**

Error Result:

```
● httpd.service - The Apache HTTP Server
Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/httpd.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-09-04 07:06:47 EDT; 47s ago
Docs: man:httpd(8)
man:apachectl(8)
Process: 13017 ExecStop=/bin/kill -WINCH ${MAINPID} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Process: 13016 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/httpd $OPTIONS -DFOREGROUND (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Main PID: 13016 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Sep 04 07:06:47 example.com systemd[1]: Starting The Apache HTTP Server...
Sep 04 07:06:47 example.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: main process exite...E
Sep 04 07:06:47 example.com kill[13017]: kill: cannot find process ""
Sep 04 07:06:47 example.com systemd[1]: httpd.service: control process ex...1
Sep 04 07:06:47 example.com systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP S....
Sep 04 07:06:47 example.com systemd[1]: Unit httpd.service entered failed....
Sep 04 07:06:47 example.com systemd[1]: httpd.service failed.

Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: What does `service httpd configtest` say?

Comment: In your first error result line it tells you two commands to try - `systemctl status httpd.service` and `journalctl -xe`. Please add (_and format_) the output of those commands to your question.

Comment: **service httpd configtest** said **'Syntax Ok'**

Answer (score 0):

So far I've found

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

works better than anything else.

```
sudo systemctl restart httpd.service
```

always seems to take an age and doesn't always do the job.